# Nginx mass virtualhosts with wordpress

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to have massvirtual hosts with wordpress installations without having to define a server block for each and every one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way this is possible if you can make all wordpress sites use the same wordpress installation, otherwise I don't think it's possible without creating a new virtual host for each server because every server has a different entry point (different index.php) and each request should be trimmed to pass the correct URI to the PHP file.

**EDIT**:

You can do a dynamic server name and match this to a folder in the www

```
server {
  server_name ^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
  root /var/www/$domain;
  location / {
    # normal wordpress config;
  }
}
```

This way if you add a new domain like `www.new-example.com` you can create a new folder at `/var/www/new-example.com` and it will work without playing with the nginx configuration

Comment: I already have the server loading the correct index.php etc I just need some additional Wordpress stuff and not of my website have Wordpress so is there a way of configuring this ? I was thinking maybe of using a flag that tells nginx to switch on the wordpress settings for a particular host.

Comment: will they be sub-domains or sub-folders?

Comment: They are subfolders so www.mysite.com is located at /var/www/sites/mysite.com/www/

Comment: my question is, are they like `sub1.example.com` and `sub2.example.com` or are they `example.com/site1` and `example.com/site2` or do each have different name

Comment: they are like the first